# Specify varying-coefficient and factor-level replicate in mgcv

Tags: r, mgcv

I am using the `mgcv` package in R to fit smooths.  I am interested in fitting a varying-coefficient model, where the varying-coefficient smooth also varies based on a factor variable.

According to the `mgcv` documentation, when specifying a smooth with `s()`, the `by` argument can take either a numeric variable, in which case a varying-coefficient model is fit, OR a factor variable, in which case a replicate of the smooth is produced for each factor level.  However, the documentation does not say how to specify a model with a varying-coefficient effect AND have that effect differ across multiple factor levels.  I dont see any reason why this wouldnt be possible, so it is somewhat odd that these two different effects are specified by the same argument.

Answer (score 1):

**I reached out to the creator of the `mgcv` package with this question, and here is the response I got**:

This should be possible, but there may be an identifiability problem.
Suppose f is a factor with levels "a", "b", "c", x is your smoothing
variable and z your covariate of interest, you want a model something like

y = z s_f(x) + noise

Then

```
da <- as.numeric(f="a")*z
db <- as.numeric(f="b")*z
dc <- as.numeric(f="c")*z

gam(y ~ s(x,by=da) + s(x,by=db) + s(x,by=dc) - 1)
```

would fit the model.  The only problem with this is the `-1`. We need it
because otherwise the intercepts of the smooths are confounded with the
overall intercept. `-1` deals with the identifiability in this simple
case, but won't in some other situations - for example if you include a
factor variable parametrically in the model, or have a second set of
smooths conditional on factor levels in this way.

A possibility  in these cases would be to use the `select=TRUE` argument
to gam, which will formally remove the identifiability problem.